# NSKeyedUnarchiver issue with unarchiving

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a `NSData` which is returned from an `ASIHTTPRequest` and I want to be able to unarchive this. However some `NSData` can be unarchived and some can't.

The issue is how do I figure out which one can and which one can't? `unarchiveObjectWithData` will crash if I provide a data that can't be unarchived.

Comment: NSData is a property value so it is easily archived/unarchived.. there shouldn't be any problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to archive all custom objects if you specify **how it's supposed to be encoded/decoded**. If you are not sure how to do this check out this tutorial: [Click Here!](http://keeptheseinmind.blogspot.com/2011/10/nskeyedarchiver-tutorial.html)
If you are storing basic datatypes, using NSUserDefaults is also viable.

Answer (score 0):

I think try-catch block is what you need. Take a look at: [Exception Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocExceptionHandling.html)